# Returning Only Non-Duplicate Rows in Same Table?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, distinct

From the following `Produce` table,

```
FRUITS                PRICE
Granny Smith Apple    $ 10
Golden Orchard Apple  $ 15
Spotted Banana        $ 20
Small Banana          $ 15
Green Pear            $ 25
Seedless Grapes       $ 10
Juicy Watermelon      $ 30
```

I want to return the following result set where all duplicate rows are not included:

```
FRUITS                PRICE
Spotted Banana        $ 20
Green Pear            $ 25
Juicy Watermelon      $ 30
```

My SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fruits, price 
FROM produce
WHERE price IN 
     (SELECT DISTINCT price
     FROM produce);
```

My code works but it's not producing the desired result set above.

EDIT:

The following query produces one of the columns (non-duplicate price) I need for the result set but i just need the fruits' names column next to it:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT price
     FROM produce
```

Comment: what are duplicates here?

Comment: the prices $10 and $15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
select min(fruit) as fruit, price
from produce
group by price
having count(*) = 1;
```

Because the `having` clause limits the number of rows to a price to one row, the `min()` is the value on that row.

If you had more columns, then you would probably do this the more traditional way using window functions:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, count(*) over (partition by price) as cnt
      from produce p
     ) p
where cnt = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by price, and ignore all those fruits having count more than 1

```
select p.FRUITS, p.PRICE from produce p
group by p.PRICE
having count(p.PRICE)=1;
```

Comment: `ORA-00979 not a group by expression`

Comment: @afrose - it won't.

Comment: I tried for mysql here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e20f1/4
It was giving the correct output. I don't understand why `min(fruit)`  was necessary

Comment: @MT0 plz do check the fiddle

Comment: @afrose Not sure why you want me to look at the fiddle - its not my down vote. However, change the database from MySQL to Oracle and run the same query and you will get an `ORA-00979` exception.